# Wordpress Category for pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm having a problem with receiving the value from `%category%` in `$wp_rewrite->page_structure` :

```
function custom_page_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root .'/%category%/%pagename%'; 
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules',1 );
```

How can I receive the `%category%` in a `$wp_rewrite->page_structure`?

Now it returns:
http://example.com/%category%/the-page-slug/

Instead:
http://example.com/my-cat-slug/the-page-slug/

---

Note Categories for pages are working well:

http://example.com/my-cat-slug/
returns all pages from this category.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
function rudr_post_permalink( $url, $post ){
    if( !is_object( $post ) )
        $post = get_post( $post_id );

    $replace = $post->post_name;

    /* We should use a post ID to make a replacement. It is required if you use urf-8 characters in your URLs */

    if( $post->ID == 1 ) 
        $replace = 'hello-planet';
    if( $post->ID == 12 ) 
        $replace = 'Contacts';

    $url = str_replace($post->post_name, $replace, $url );
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
add_filter( 'page_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
```

Which is explained [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/change-specific-urls.html)

You can change the `if( $post->ID == 1 )` to anything you need.

I have changed the whole code to add categories in the URL's when it are pages.

Regards, Danny